# How to generate a matrix with randomly distributed clusters of numbers in MatLab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, random

I can generate a matrix of randomly placed 1's and 0's by using `round(rand(100,100))` for instance.
How can I generate a similar matrix where instead of 1's there are a given number of randomly distributed square sub-matrices of 1's of a given size? For example:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The matrix above has `4` randomly placed sub-matrices of 1's of size `2`.

Comment: Can the sub-matrices overlap?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. If you could suggest a way to incorporate the option to overlap or not, that would be great too.

Comment: errr... why is this downvoted? Seems like a legitimate question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they might overlap, here is one possible answer:

```
rows = 8;
cols = 8;
nSquares = 4;
sizeSquares = 2;
mat = zeros(rows, cols);
for ii = 1:nSquares
    row = randi(rows - sizeSquares + 1);
    col = randi(cols - sizeSquares + 1);
    mat(row:row+sizeSquares-1,col:col+sizeSquares-1) = 1;
end
```

Result:

```
mat =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

**EDIT:** assuming they cannot overlap, here is one possible way:

```
rows = 8;
cols = 8;
nSquares = 4;
sizeSquares = 3;
mat = zeros(rows, cols);
createdSquares = 0;
for ii = 1:nSquares
    [r, c] = find(mat(1:rows - sizeSquares + 1, 1:cols - sizeSquares + 1) == 0);
    if isempty(r)
        break;
    end   

    idx = randi(numel(r));
    row = r(idx);
    col = c(idx);
    mat(max(1, row - sizeSquares + 1:row + sizeSquares - 1),max(1, col - sizeSquares + 1):col+sizeSquares - 1) = ...
        mat(max(1, row - sizeSquares + 1:row + sizeSquares - 1),max(1, col - sizeSquares + 1):col+sizeSquares - 1) + 1;
    mat(row:row+sizeSquares-1,col:col+sizeSquares-1) = Inf;
    createdSquares = createdSquares + 1;
end
mat = mat == Inf;
```

What is does is this:

- Create the matrix, filled with zeros.
- Find a random 'zero' position. It'll be the top-left corner of the new square. Hence, it only looks for 'zeros' on valid positions (a zero at the lower-right corner cannot be used to create a square with size > 2, for example).
- Fill the region with `Inf`. Before that, it fills the area above and at the left of the region, incrementing 1 (`Inf`'s will not be incremented). This way, those areas cannot be selected on the second step, thus preventing overlapping.

**Note:** it's not guaranteed all squares will be created. This might happen if the matrix is filled in such a way there is not enough room for a new square (it might be impossible to have a solution, depending on the values of `rows`, `cols` and `nSquares`). That's why you have the `createdSquares` variable, which indicates how many squares were created.

Comment: and if they don't overlap? :]

Comment: Isn't that a good starting point for you to develop the non-overlapping version? :) **Hint:** you could check if the submatrix already have any 1's inside before the assigning 1.

Comment: I thought about that :) but the matrix I'll be working with will be at least 1000x1000 so I was hoping there was a faster way of doing it without double checking a lot of steps